# How to get true/false from $("").on()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is possible to get boolean from this?

```
$(".svgobjects").on("mousedown", function(){
        console.log("clicked");
});
```

I want to check if user mousedown on one of divs with ".svgobjects" class.

**EDIT:**

why this code returns always "false"?

```
var ifclicked=false;
    $(".svgobjects").on("mousedown", function(){
        console.log("clicked");
        ifclicked = true;
    });
    console.log("ifclicked "+ifclicked);
```

[This is screen from google chrome console log](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59608446/Fora%20pytania/chrome.png)

Comment: I don't think it is possible like that.... one possible solution is to set a flag on mouse down and set it to false on mouse up

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700066/check-if-mousedown-with-an-if-statement

Answer (score 4):

Store the boolean value to some var:

```
var clicked = false;
$(".svgobjects").on("mousedown", function(){
  clicked = true;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You simply use a variable

```
var IsSvgobjectsMousedown = false;
$(".svgobjects").on("mousedown", function(){
        IsSvgobjectsMousedown = true;
        console.log("clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is Using  [data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

> Store arbitrary data associated with the specified element. Returns the value that was set.

```
$(".svgobjects").on("mousedown", function(){
      $(".svgobjects").data("clicked",  "yes");
});

alert($(".example").data("clicked"));
```

For specific object

```
 $(".svgobjects").on("mousedown", function(){
          $(this).data("clicked",  "yes");
    });
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshbm13/asCVU/3/)

with the `data()`  you can store some data to the `element` when it being clicked.And retrieve that information ,When you need it :)

**Edit  after update the Question:**

That means you are logging  the `variable` ,before the callback,Which is updating the variable after the logging done.

```
$(".example").append("<input  class='svgobjects'</input>")
var ifclicked=false;
    $(".svgobjects").on("mousedown", function(){
        console.log("clicked");
        ifclicked = true;
        alert(ifclicked);
    });
    console.log("ifclicked "+ifclicked);
```

[**Demo for the Edit**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshbm13/asCVU/6/)

Comment: but what if user end "mousedown" on my object? All of previously clicked objects will keep "clicked" "yes".

Comment: In such cases use `this`  if you want to set to specific element.And regarding to your  update in the question ,Is that element you are doing `mouse down` is dynamically added ??? If no use normal mousedown  other wise see my demo.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is not working as you expect is because the code that you have written does not execute in a linear fashion. The '$(".svgobjects").on("mousedown",...' block is an event listener with a callback that will only fire once that event occurs.

If you are looking at performing a task once something is clicked, perhaps wrap it in a function and call that function within the mousedown callback.

Answer (score 0):

you will always receive false that ways, you code order is not right

```
var ifclicked=false;
    $(".svgobjects").on("mousedown", function(){
        console.log("clicked");
        ifclicked = true;
        console.log("ifclicked "+ifclicked);
    });
```

Now it will return true, you earlier sequence wasn't correct

Answer (score 0):

You should move the last code into the callback like below,

```
var ifclicked=false;
$(".svgobjects").on("mousedown", function(){
    console.log("clicked");
    ifclicked = true;
    console.log("ifclicked: "+ifclicked);
});
```